# Diff between two date in excel with mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried using text function to calculate the difference but it considers the data to be in dd/mm/yyyy format whereas my data is in mm/dd format.

```
=TEXT(3/4/2015 18:30-3/6/2015 8:45,"h:mm")
```

the output is 14:15.

Comment: How does it matter if you only need hours and minutes?

Comment: I don't recommend specifying dates like this in formula. Either use `=DATE()+TIME()` or write dates in separate cells and use references in your formula like `=TEXT(A1-A2,"h:mm")`. Plus you will not get more than 24 hours like this, as this format displays *time component* of date, not the difference in hours and minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue used

```
=TEXT(3/4/2015 18:30-3/6/2015 8:45,"[h]:mm")
```

now got the difference has 38:15 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when we do time calculations, we like to get the time represented in a common base.

examples of common base:

- 1,10,100,1000,.. <- base 10
- 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,..<- base 2

the date formats, are not really in a common base, as:

- years are in base 10
- months and hours are in base 12
- days are in variable base, either approximately 30 or approximately 360
- minutes and seconds in base 60,

and fractions of seconds are .. well base 10 fractions..

on top of that we do not agree across cultures if we zero-index when counting.
so i.e. what is the first day of the week?
Where I live, I would say **monday**, but several other cultures have **sunday** as the first one..

so calculating differences between two dates can be difficult.

The trick of using TEXT for calculations without using DATEVALUE, have given me alot of problems.

which is why I recommend that you look at this:
http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel

and use **Option Three - Splitting the text into its constituent parts and recombining them into a date**